# How to make clearTimeout() happen within setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, settimeout

I have a setTimeout function already running to make a watch work, but I want to clearTimeout on this already running function when I clock on a button, but only after a few seconds. So ideally, I want a clearTimeout() inside another setTimeout() function, but I can't seem to get it working.

I have this code at the moment:

```
alarm.click(function() {
    water.animate(anim);    
    setTimeout(function () { clearTimeout(time); }, 3000);
});

var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() },1000);
```

But it does it clears it straight away rather than after 3 seconds. What can I do to make it clear after 3 seconds?
edited my code, still not working :(.

Comment: You are calling the method and assigning what it returns right away. Look at your second setTimeout line and compare it to the first in the code above.

Comment: `setTimeout(clearTimeout.bind(window,time), 3000);` or wrap it in anonymous function. And you could there just use referenced method: `var time = setTimeout(startTime,1000);`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it straight away, but you need a callback.

```
setTimeout(function () { clearTimeout(time); }, 3000);
```

```js
function startTime() {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += 'starttime<br>';
}

function set() {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += 'set<br>';
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += 'clear3000<br>';
        clearTimeout(time);
    }, 3000);
}

var time = setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += 'clear1000<br>';
    startTime();
}, 1000);

set();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var time = setTimeout(function(){startTime(time)},1000);
```

And in startTime you clear `time`

```
function startTime(time) {
     cleartTimeout(time);
     ...
}
```